# Preciso de ajuda, estou utilizando Node e Request Form para fazer Scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, requisição, scraping

Estou tentando desenvolver uma aplicação para pegar dados de um determinado site e enviar para o banco de dados. Seria simples se não tivesse que fazer requisição para acessar esses dados.

Como estou começando, talvez esteja me expressando errado, mas vou tentar detalhar o máximo possível para que fique claro.

Ao acessar o site (http://preco.anp.gov.br/include/Resumo_Por_Municipio_Index.asp), você da de cara com um input, a qual você deve inserir um valor pertinente, depois aparece um input select para você selecionar um dado baseado no valor pertinente que você tinha escolhido anteriormente, depois aparece um captcha.

Notei que mesmo sem digitar o captcha, apenas apertando submit, a requisição (POST) é enviada para o servidor. Depois disso, para acessar as informações pertinentes, preciso apenas alterar o link para (http://preco.anp.gov.br/include/Resumo_Por_Municipio_Postos.asp). Acredito que isso ocorre devido o fato da requisição estar armazenada nos cookies.

Iniciei meu código em NODE:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
const request = require('request');

var form = {
    selSemana: '1087*De 12/04/2020 a 18/04/2020',
    desc_Semana: 'de 12/04/2020 a 18/04/2020',
    cod_Semana: '1087',
    txtMunicipio:'',
    selMunicipio: '1033*MINASGERAIS',
    image1: ''
};

var formData = querystring.stringify(form);
var contentLength = formData.length;

request({
    headers: {
      'Content-Length': contentLength,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    uri: 'http://preco.anp.gov.br/include/Resumo_Por_Municipio_Index.asp',
    body: formData,
    method: 'POST'
  }, function (err, res, body) {
        console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);
        console.log(res);
  });
```

Até ai consigo fazer a requisição POST, mas já tentei de diversas formas levar os cookies para o GET no segundo line, porém não consigo. Será que alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiro que use puppeteer para controlar o navegador e digitar o valor no input e preencher o campo select, mas como voce disse que tem captcha, é dificil automatizar a tarefa de webscraping em qualquer biblioteca, seja ela puppeteer ou não.

Comment: As requisições de cookies em que ficavam armazenados os inputs eram geradas utilizando o google analytics, a melhor opção de fato é o puppetteer.